# Getting TypeError Exception while using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: typescript, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

I am writing an visual studio extension and trying to send image via http request with using multipart/form-data.

```
  const fs = require('fs');
  const form = new FormData();
  const f = fs.readFileSync('/IMG.jpg');
  const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(`${request.readyState}`);
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(`Successfully uploaded at: ${request.response.date}`);
    }
  };
  request.open('POST', `https://api.trello.com/1/card/${idCard}/attachments`);
  form.append("key", this.getKey());
  form.append("token", this.getToken());
  form.append("file", f);
  form.append("mimeType", "image/jpg");
  form.append("name", "My Awesome File");
  //request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
  request.send(form);
```

At `request.send(form)` line I got exception

```
  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "string" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer. Received type object
```

All examples of using XmlHttpRequest show that FormData can be used in this method. I installed XmlHttpRequest and FormData from npm for Node.js.

How to send this FormData?

Answer (score 0):

XmlHttpRequest from npm have an issue [#174](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest/issues/174). It's not supporting FormData. You can use method `FormData.getBuffer()`.